# Astronaut is deluded into taking his helmet off (and dies)

Tags: story-identification

It's a short story about two astronauts who land on a planet. They think they see green hills, flowers, breathable air. Despite the warnings coming from their base, one of them removes his helmet. At the base they see his head explode, but the second astronaut sees his companion running free and happy, inviting him to take off his helmet too and join him. Torn between his companion's entreaties and his superiors' warnings, the second astronaut finally gives in to the delusion and takes off his helmet.

What short story is it? Who is the author?

Comment: Is it possible you're misremembering, or getting confused with the novel "Wool"?

Comment: *Wool* never had two Cleaners outside at the same time, and the Cleaners had no need to take off their helmets; their suits failed in a matter of fifteen minutes or so.

Comment: This sounds very familiar. As I recall it, there was ambiguity where the second astronaut wasn't sure if he was hallucinating the other astronaut being fine, or mission command's words.

Comment: This sounds like something Q would have done to the members of an Away Team from the Enterprise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [1st Mars landing story-Read in eighties](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/205284/1st-mars-landing-story-read-in-eighties)

Comment: @fectin - The OP has not confirmed that any answers currently submitted are correct yet, and until they do, this question should not be flagged as a duplicate.

Comment: @LogicDictates fair; my error.

Comment: @fectin - It's a common error. Pretty sure I made it myself in my early days here.

Comment: @user57467 Except the Enterprise crew almost never landed on a planet that required them to wear space suits, or really any kind of protective gear whatsoever.  The only times I can recall them putting on suits was in some of the movies (e.g. *The Motion Picture*, *First Contact*, *Into Darkness*, for one from each set), and that was generally just for going outside the ship in deep space, not on a planet.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman they had suits on for "The Naked Time", but took the gloves off to scratch an itch, or some stupid thing.

Comment: @user57467 That doesn't sound like Q at all to me. Q was cruel at times, but he was not sadistic.

Comment: pls mark answere as accepted. it is always considered polite to come back to your questions even after they are answered

Comment: Note duplicate closure is ok per policy since OP accepted the answer via comment.

Answer (score 35):

I think this is "[The Gods of Mars](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41366)" by Gardner Dozois, Jack Dann, and Michael Swanwick.

An older question (link below) says

> The two guys in the lander come out and what they see is an Edgar Rice Burroughs kind of landscape. The guy in the mothership is convinced, of course that they are hallucinating. Finally one of them takes off his helmet. His buddy on the surface sees him walking around with no ill effects, but the guy in the mothership reports that his suit telemetry says he's dead. Finally, the second guy takes his helmet off too.

Full answer here [1st Mars landing story-Read in eighties](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/205284/1st-mars-landing-story-read-in-eighties/205294#205294)

Comment: I asked question some time back.

Comment: Yes!! That’s it, it’s “The Gods of Mars”! Reading it, I remembered details I had forgotten about, like the swim in the canal. Thank you!!

Comment: @Klara you are most welcome! If this is indeed the story you were looking for, please click the gray checkmark beside the answer to mark it as solved.